# utility of the authentification system created by FosOAuthServerBundle

Tags: rest, symfony

I am developping a Restful web application with Symfony2 and I will use FosOAuthServerBundle and OAuth2,I started to read some tutorials, but one thing I didn't understand,in my application I have already an authentication system in which the admin put his login and password,but the implementation of this bundle in my application adds a second authentification system to my app,for this reason as I have understood I should add a button in my login page to use this bundle and having the access token to protect my rest web service
My question is,what are the advantages of this second authentification system,espitially my application is for one user "the administrator"??
My second question is,is it possible to combine this functionality with my login system that I have created from the beginning
thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage of using oAuth2 is that is standardized, so you can use any client in any language out there to get an access token.

If you have a single admin user, probably you don't need it but is up to you decide that.

I'm quite sure you can integrate your auth system to the oAuth bundle by following the symfony2 security documentation and implementing an user provider

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html

Comment: thanks muka for your reply :) and what do you think about using API keys in my case?? thanks again

Comment: You may use api key as well without oAuth2, see this for an example
 http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html

Comment: thanks muka for the link :),so what's the difference between using OAuth2 and API keys,with both of them I can generate access tokens

Comment: That one is oAuth2 based on specification and the other is your symfony implementation of api key. Basically, with oauth you have to get a token with additional mechanism. Read the the  oAuth2 spec or some introduction for more details